Сказуемое перед перечислением
Вокруг кист отмечается размягчение ткани, инфильтрация эозинофилами, кровоизлияния, сращение  оболочек.
У больных отмечается повышение температуры тела, слабость, головные боли, потливость, снижение массы тела, боли в груди.
Слово "отмечается" здесь корректно в единственном числе или надо поставить "отмечаются"?

Везде нужно множественное число, ввиду перечисления. И ещё правильно "размягчение тканей", а не "ткани", скорее всего.

"По улице встречаете вы и обгоняете команды солдат, пластунов,
офицеров; изредка встречаются женщина или ребенок, но женщина уже
не в шляпке, а матроска в старой шубейке и в солдатских сапогах."
Толстой.


"У больных отмечаются общее недомогание, головная боль,
плаксивость, снижение памяти, нарушение сна."  Профессиональные
болезни: учеб. пособие для студ. высш. учеб. заведений,
обучающихся по специальности 033300 «Безопасность жизнедеятельности» /
авт.-сост. Т. Я. Биндюк, О. В. Бессчетнова. — Балашов: Николаев, 2007.

Случай употребления единственного числа:

"У половины больных отмечается тахикардия, у четверти — артериальная
гипотония, в отдельных случаях олигурия." И статьи Г. К.
Аликеева, кандидат медицинских наук, Н. Д. Ющук, доктор медицинских
наук, профессор, академик РАМН, Н. Х. Сафиуллина, кандидат медицинских
наук, А. В. Сундуков, доктор медицинских наук, профессор, Г. М.
Кожевникова, доктор медицинских наук, профессор, МГМСУ, Москва.

Множественное число из того же источника:

У больных отмечаются: тяжелый метаболический ацидоз, сгущение крови,
повышение ее удельного веса, ухудшение реологических свойств крови,
гипокалиемия, повышение содержания белка и др.

То есть, можно и двоеточие поставить, перечисление же.
Про ткани:

"Мацерация животных тканей имеет место при длительном соприкосновении
их с водой. Ею пользуются при изготовлении скелетов, гистологических
препаратов, действуя на трупы или отдельные ткани водой, растворами
щелочей, кислот и другими веществами." Большая Советская Энциклопедия.-

Для сравнения:\
"При смягчении ткани зачастую улучшается и внешний вид изделия, так что проводить эту процедуру весьма желательно." - про текстиль.
В теории, можно употреблять "растительная ткань", но "ткани животных"/ "ткани организма". Либо:

"Ткань, ткани. 2. Группа клеток организма, выполняющих в нем ту или
иную функцию (анат.). Мышечная ткань. Нервная ткань. Соединительная
ткань." Ушаков.

Чтобы употребить в единственном числе, нужно указать какая по типу ткань.

...изредка встречаются женщина или ребенок... Да, тут всё верно с мн. числом. У Розенталя об этом тоже говорится (можно посмотреть в ссылке):  Обычно такая форма согласования бывает, когда подлежащие обозначают лиц... / И — ни в одном предложении из вопроса нет двоеточия.  / Так что использование единственного числа ошибкой не будет.

@РиммаМихайлова я полагаю есть раница в стилистике. Если это художественное описание, то да, но если это научный стиль и термины, то нет. В научном стиле должно быть чёткое согласование элементов фраз, а в художественном допустимы всякие приложения и тп. То есть, должно быть всё четко и максимально просто, без художественных изысков. Ну и со словом "ткани" в ед. числе есть проблема.

Употребляют и в единственном, и во множественном числе. Размягчение ткани легкого... (https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/enc_medicine/23777/%D0%9F%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8F%CC%81%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F)  / ...и размягчение ткани в зоне повреждения. / Нередко в центре опухоли (независимо от ее величины) имеется размягчение ткани... / Это уже специфические (сугубо медицинские) моменты.

@РиммаМихайлова потому что "такни лёгкого", есть указание какой ткани, без указания какой ткани это слово не употребляется. Потому что "ткани лёгкого" или более верно "лёгочная ткань" - это словосочетание есть сложный термин, по одиночки слова не будут терминами, только в сочетании.

Правильно:
Вокруг кист отмечаются размягчение ткани, инфильтрация эозинофилами, кровоизлияния, сращение оболочек.
У больных отмечаются повышение температуры тела, слабость, головные боли, потливость, снижение массы тела, боли в груди.
Пояснение
В общем случае согласование в числе ряда однородных членов со сказуемым возможно по смыслу (мн. число) или по форме (ед. число), поэтому надо сделать выбор.
Также надо учитывать специфику текста. В медицинской литературе свои правила оформления, даже есть специальные учебники для формирования навыков устной и письменной профессиональной речи, ведения диалога со стационарным больным, оформления Истории болезни и т. д.
Поэтому логично предположить, что здесь будет согласование по смыслу во мн. числе перед рядом признаков.  Согласование по форме  обычно характерно для художественных текстов, где важна сочетаемость рядом стоящих слов.
Пример:
Нередко отмечаются ожирение, расстройство кожной трофики, врождённые пороки сердца, атрезии и стенозы пищевого канала, диафрагмальные грыжи.
Вадим Петрович Глухов, Дефектология. Специальная педагогика и специальная психология. Курс лекций, 2017

• Заглянем в "Справочник по правописанию, произношению, литературному редактированию" (Розенталь Д.Э., Джанджакова Е.В., Кабанова Н.П.):

§190. Согласование сказуемого с однородными подлежащими
1. При прямом порядке слов (сказуемое следует за однородными подлежащими) обычно употребляется форма множественного числа сказуемого, при обратном порядке (сказуемое предшествует подлежащим) — форма единственного числа. Например:
а) Жара и засуха стояли более трех недель (Л. Толстой);
б) До Райского и Марфиньки долетел грубый говор, грубый смех, смешанные голоса, внезапно притихшие... (Гончаров)... Несся тяжелый топот кованых сапог и крикливые бабьи взвизги... (Серафимович); По земле, истомленной в зное, разливалась свежесть, прохлада и неизъяснимая легкость... (В.Солоухин).
Указанные положения не носят категорического характера, постпозитивное сказуемое может стоять в форме единственного, а препозитивное — в форме множественного числа(особенно часто в технической литературе).

✦ Слово "отмечается" здесь корректно в единственном числе?..
Да, употребление сказуемого в единственном числе здесь вполне корректно (если только подлежащее во множественном числе не стоит первым).
• Примеры:
Новое заболевание напоминает Эболу и Марбург. У больных отмечается повышение температуры, боли в голове, общая усталость и обильное носовое кровотечение (из статьи);
Отмечается инфильтрация, отек и увеличение рыхлости синовиальной оболочки (из медицинского справочника болезней).

Вот я не уверен, что корректно. Потому что "долетел" про что-то описанное далее, а отмечаются (симптомы/признаки) - пропущен обобщающий термин.

Сказуемое, стоящее перед однородными подлежащими, обычно ставится в форме единственного числа.
Поэтому было бы:

Вокруг кист отмечается размягчение ткани, инфильтрация эозинофилами,
кровоизлияния, сращение оболочек.

Но из-за подлежащего мн.ч. "головные боли" уместнее применить множественное число и изменить порядок слов в обоих случаях, вынеся подлежащее мн.ч. вперёд:

У больных отмечаются головные боли, повышение температуры тела, слабость,
потливость, снижение массы тела, боли в груди.

Ну, и стилистически пассивный залог портит фразу, хотя, если вы для медицинских документов пишете, то кому там какое дело.

Ну... В первом предложении тоже имеется подлежащее во мн. числе. (И пишете, наверно?)

@РиммаМихайлова, да, исправил
